# AWS Cloudformation Drift returns differences because object order is not respected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have done a AWS Cloudformation Drift detection and I get Differences/Errors back from the drift.

After investigating about the errors I've noticed there was no errors but in reallity the errors came from the fact the template file and the drift file were nor ordering the elements on the same order. We're using JSON and I know the order is not respected when you load it but that's quite annoying if Drift detects it as errors.

Is there a way to make it ignore the order issue?

Comment: Do you want Drift detection mechanism to ignore the ordering of elements?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't make sense for it to consider the order as an error while an object is never ordered